# pyodbc upsert error - SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 3 parameters were supplied', 'HY000'

Tags: pyodbc, impala, upsert, apache-kudu

I am using pyodbc, impala driver for kudu on cloudera 5.16, Python 3.6.10 to do an upsert into kudu table. Insert works fine but upsert fails. I am getting an error: *SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 3 parameters were supplied', 'HY000'* . The code looks like below:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=my-impala-dsn',autocommit=True) 
crsr = conn.cursor() 

crsr.execute("UPSERT INTO mydb.mytable (col1,col2,col3) values(?,?,?)", val1,val2,val3)
```

Any thoughts on the error?

Comment: Is impala version is more than 2.8? Is primary key defined properly on the table?

Comment: impalad version 2.12.0-cdh5.16.1,  yes primary key is fine. Kudu table cannot be created without proper primary keys. Also if I run using DBeaver SQL editor the upsert works fine. Looks like Pyodbc has some limitations in upsert.

Comment: Hmm, that's good to know. I think the way you passing arguments is incorrect. Can you try passing it in an array? Like `update t values (?,?,?), [V1,v2,v3])`

Comment: @ebeb, how did you solve your problem?

Comment: I think I just went with delete the row and insert new row instead of upsert as far as I remember.